# javascript - creating dynamic price ranges (not slider)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, filter

I have the following list of objects, for example, as the data source:

```
var data = [
{"id": 456, "name": "ngf", "price": 9},
{"id": 576, "name": "ghdf", "price": 14},
{"id": 756, "name": "dtdf", "price": 16},
{"id": 743, "name": "fsd", "price": 19},
{"id": 354, "name": "gf", "price": 28},
{"id": 678, "name": "hjmd", "price": 42},
{"id": 783, "name": "fgh", "price": 55},
{"id": 345, "name": "gdv", "price": 60},
{"id": 785, "name": "ghj", "price": 67},
{"id": 869, "name": "hd", "price": 87},
{"id": 234, "name": "hgf", "price": 95}
]
```

(the list is sorted by the objects' price value on purpose, because that's what it's like in my code for real)

This list actually represents a data source for products shown on the page.
Now, I need to create dynamic price ranges for filtering this list for display, in the following way:

- Up to $10
- $11 - 30
- $31 - $50
- > $50

These ranges are NOT arbitrary here and are specifically based on the price values in the current list of objects (products, as I've mentioned). Nevertheless, it is only an example and in the real code on my website, this list is dynamic and the prices can vary in a very wide overall range (for example, it can be from $0.5 to $1,000). Even the amount of products in this list is dynamic. The only that's not dynamic here is always having **4** ranges of prices, where the first if "upto x" and the last is "above y".

I need to write a javascript code that can take this list and its dynamic prices and create the appropriate ranges.

Please note that I already have some kind of an algorithm for that (sorting the list from low to high, getting the average of it, getting the percentage of each of the prices against the entire amount of products and so on), but I haven't been able to implement it in JS code de-facto. That's why I'm asking here for a working JavaScript code and not just the logic or theoretical idea.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You would need to define a delta too. $10 or $100 or $1

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: If your delta is 10, then you have ranges from 1-10 with 9, 11-20 with 14,16,19, 21-29 with 28 in it and so on. If you have a delta of 50 you have 0-49 with 9,14,16,119,24,42 and so on. In your example you have a starting delta of 20, then of 30 then the rest

Comment: First of all, I remind you that the prices are dynamic and not preset. With every load of the page, there could be different prices for all the items in the list. Even the amount of items in the list is dynamic, for that matter. I need this calculation to occur every page load and have the appropriate **4** ranges of prices to cover the entire range of prices (from the lowest to the highest in the current set). That's the essence of the question - how do I do that programmatically in JavaScript?

Comment: Ok - it was not obvious that your examples were the actual ranges. Since SO is not e-lancing.com, please show us what you tried and ask specific questions as detailed in the [help] - I do not mind writing custom code, but I charge.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, well. I found interesting so here is a solution

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/d2o1ojv9/)

```js
var data = [
{"id": 456, "name": "ngf", "price": 9},
{"id": 576, "name": "ghdf", "price": 14},
{"id": 756, "name": "dtdf", "price": 16},
{"id": 743, "name": "fsd", "price": 19},
{"id": 354, "name": "gf", "price": 28},
{"id": 678, "name": "hjmd", "price": 42},
{"id": 783, "name": "fgh", "price": 55},
{"id": 345, "name": "gdv", "price": 60},
{"id": 785, "name": "ghj", "price": 67},
{"id": 869, "name": "hd", "price": 87},
{"id": 234, "name": "hgf", "price": 95}
], 
    ranges = [0,10,30,50,Number.MAX_VALUE],
    buckets = {},
    numBuckets=ranges.length-1;

// create the object to hold the ranges
for (var i=0;i<ranges.length-1;i++) {
    buckets["bucket"+i]= {limit: [ranges[i],ranges[i+1]],bucket: []};
}    
// fill the buckets
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var b in buckets) {
        var bucket = buckets[b], price = data[i].price; 
        if (price > bucket.limit[0] && price<= bucket.limit[1]) {
            bucket.bucket.push(data[i]);
        }
    }
}
// access the data again and display it
for (var i=0;i<numBuckets;i++) {
    var data = buckets["bucket"+i];
    console.log(i,data);
    for (var j=0;j<data.bucket.length;j++) {
        console.log(j,data.bucket)
        document.getElementById("range"+i).innerHTML+=data.bucket[j].name+":"+data.bucket[j].price+"<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("range"+i).innerHTML+='<hr/>';
}
```

```html
Up to $10
<div id="range0"></div>
$11 - 30
<div id="range1"></div>
$31 - $50
<div id="range2"></div>
> $50
<div id="range3"></div>
```